# How does one go about developer scalability and code-reuse in Flash?

Tags: flash, code-reuse

I've so far dabbled in Flash doing 1-man shows for quite some time, but have never done any big projects with it, where actually source management and code-reuse was truly necessary. However I'm considering Flash for a new project, but this time around it's won't be a 1-man show, that's when it struck me that I had no experience of how one is supposed to do that with flash.

What are some good tips or resources that could help us figure out a good workflow?

Comment: that's when it 'struck' you, not 'stroke' you. :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Good communication
- Don't work in .fla's. 100% of the code in .as files
- UML (at least discussed)
- Different tasks for everybody
- Comments in commits to code repository
- "Manage your code so that anybody can at any time take over your job"
- Consider [the bus factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_factor)

With junior developers it's also good to go through basic stuff such as package structures etc, just so that everybody is on the same page.

I think it's also good if somebody is kind of like a technical manager of the project, overseeing what the developers are doing. It may also be one of the developers but i think it's important to have one person who knows what everybody else is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Antti has a bunch of good ones, externalizing code and appointing a leader in particular, I'd just add that when you're picking different tasks for everyone, tell people to code their piece as a modular class that provides the functionality you'll need - that'll make the code more reuseable in the future, and make integration smoother as well.